# "x is undefined" when clicking onclick event (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

I'm trying to debug someone else's code.
I have an onclick event:

```
function onclick(event)
{
javascript:initpage(164725) 
}
```

When the event is clicked I am getting an "JavaScript runtime error: 'initpage' is undefined" error.
I found the initpage function in a separate file, this function definition is not being detected when the event is clicked.

How can I point the onclick event to the initpage function definition so that the error goes away?(At least I think that's the issue). Thanks!

EDIT: I appear to have missed the obvious: initpage != InitPage, however I cannot access the onclick function to change it as it shows up in a dynamic file that only appears to exist when the program is running, the file is called script block [dynamic]. Quite confusing for a newb

initpage function:

```
function InitPage(viewRecentID) {
    //InitPage code

    }, function () { });
}
```

Comment: Typo: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `initpage !== InitPage`

Comment: I appear to have missed the obvious, however I cannot access the onclick function as it appears in a dynamic file that only appears to exist when the program is running, the file is called script block [dynamic]. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language - your code is looking for a function `initpage()`, but the actual function is called `InitPage()`. Change your code to this:

```
InitPage(164725);
```

Comment: Duh, I didn't see the obvious. However, the onclick function lives in a dynamic file called script block [dynamic]. This file only appears to exist when the program is running, so I cannot change initpage to InitPage...